# The procedure entry point_except_handler4_common could not be located in the dynamic link library msvcrt.dll

Tags: vb6, windows-7

As I had feared some of our old VB6 projects are not playing nice with Windows 7. Some of our customers have already upgraded and our one product is returning this error every time you run the executable:

`The procedure entry point_except_handler4_common could not be located in the dynamic link library msvcrt.dll`

First thing I tried was creating a .local in the folder so it uses all the DLL and OCX files packaged with the product.  That didn't do anything, though I'm not sure if this .local trick still works in Win7.

Tried turning on compatibility for several previous versions of Windows, that had no effect either.

Hopefully someone else has some more suggestions, as my Google-Fu has failed me on this one.

Comment: Google [suggests to me](http://blogs.msdn.com/anthonw/archive/2007/12/06/the-procedure-entry-point-except-handler4-common-could-not-be-located-in-the-dynamic-link-library-msvcrt-dll.aspx) that it's a driver problem. The Visual Basic 6 runtime [is supported by Microsoft on Windows 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbrun/ms788708.aspx), so you could try their technical support. If you have an MSDN subscription you probably have some free support incidents

Comment: Did you ever solve this? If it is solved, could you post back the solution as an answer? Might be useful to someone someday. I'll upvote it :)

Comment: Sadly no, best I could do was use Windows Virtual XP thinggy and run the software in there.  Unfortunately that only works if the person bought the more expensive versions of Win7, which most have not.

Comment: Just an update:  It seems as though Windows 7 uses the local DLL and OCX fields if you dump them in the executable's folder, regardless of the presence of a ".local" file.  So I removed some extra DLL/OCX files that were in the installed folder and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

When start prg. A.P.CS5 on screen get pop up window with message: The procedure entry point handler4 common could not be located in the dynamic link library msvcrt.dll.

I solved it this way:
FOR XP:
**Search to folder/C:windovs/system32, found icon dwmapi.dll, once found, rename to 1dwmapi.dll (or whatever, just rename it so that you can find it later if you need it for some reason) - problem solved!**